# One! Two! Fizz! Four!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

*Argh, how I hate those mean kids and their newfangled game!*
[image]
**The answer will be two words.**

Comment: I hope these aren't factorials... because 8760! is a rather large number... :P

Comment: At least on my device, all the speech bubbles seem white on the inside (except for numbers and !), but when I click on the image, only 6570!, 5169!, 3135!, 5163!, 4152!, 7215!, 7455!, 8760!, and 4548! are white, and the rest are grey.

Comment: For anyone who doesn't recognize this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz

Comment: "Apparently on some devices" -- is this *not* intentional?

Comment: @Deusovi That part of the question was edited in by another user, and I'm strongly tempted to roll back. If the OP wants to add a hint, they can do so, but other people shouldn't do it for them. The info is already here in comments.

Comment: It looks like numbers that were changed by OP in an early edit have been reverted to their pre-edit values with the most recent edit. @Who is that intentional?

Comment: @Who would you kindly respond to my previous comment? It seems like knowing the intended numbers are actually what is (currently) in the puzzle is a pretty important thing to be able to progress, and given that they changed once before and then changed back, it at least seems plausible that the reversion was unintended. Please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Partial Answer for a Picture in case it helps someone see something:

Following the rules of:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz

I have replaced all the numbers divisible by 3 with FIZZ, 5 by BUZZ, and by 15 FIZZBUZZ.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assume that both:
1. The speech bubbles all represent a group of players attempting to provide answers to the game;
2. The speech bubbles which remain when the image is clicked are the responses considered valid.

Then the rule governing whether an answer is valid is simply whether:

> It is divisible by 3

This is hinted at in the title, since:

> In the classroom mathematics game 'FizzBuzz' the word 'fizz' is used to replace all numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: 3498 does not remain but is divisible by 3. Also, 5517

Comment: @hexomino Ah, true... but then with so many kids calling out their answers all at once, maybe they just didn't get heard amid all the commotion ;-) (Will try to spot why those 2 are excluded, but given the title I would think the answer would be heavily connected to this line of thinking...)

Comment: That's not the puzzle.

Comment: please rescind your answer @Stiv

Comment: @Who What do you mean, rescind? Posting answers which turn out not to be correct is perfectly OK - someone can find the correct answer later.

Comment: @Randal'Thor; I don't think the OP wants to auto-bounty to a wrong answer!